# Compilation failure during mvn clean install

Tags: java, maven

I want to compile my project in maven and I've got this weird Exception.
after googling a lot, but I did not find anything.
My jdk is sun jdk 7 and this is my maven compiler plugin configuration

```
        <plugin>

            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <debug>true</debug>
                <optimize>true</optimize>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

and the exception

```
[INFO] Compilation failure
Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.7.0). Please file a bug at the Java Developer Connection (http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport)  after checking the Bug Parade for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report.  Thank you.
java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$VarSymbol.getConstValue(Symbol.java:1005)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.checkInit(Attr.java:2627)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:2285)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1677)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:431)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:418)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribExpr(Attr.java:449)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.enterAttributeValue(Annotate.java:203)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.enterAnnotation(Annotate.java:181)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.enterAttributeValue(Annotate.java:229)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.enterAttributeValue(Annotate.java:243)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.enterAnnotation(Annotate.java:181)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.enterAnnotations(MemberEnter.java:778)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.access$300(MemberEnter.java:56)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter$5.enterAnnotation(MemberEnter.java:746)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.flush(Annotate.java:109)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.enterDone(Annotate.java:101)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.complete(Enter.java:510)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.main(Enter.java:469)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.enterTrees(JavaCompiler.java:929)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:824)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:417)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:331)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:322)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.compileInProcess(JavacCompiler.java:420)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.compile(JavacCompiler.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:493)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:114)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Lint$AugmentVisitor.augment(Lint.java:290)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Lint.augment(Lint.java:82)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribLazyConstantValue(Attr.java:597)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$VarSymbol$1.call(Symbol.java:971)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$VarSymbol.getConstValue(Symbol.java:1003)
    ... 51 more
```

Comment: are you passing any -Xlint flag ?

Comment: which jdk are you using?

Comment: I've added more details to the question

Comment: 1.7 which update? u25?

Comment: @RKajaMohideen This error is due to the compiler, not my code

Comment: @vikingsteve Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-b147)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0-b17, mixed mode)

Comment: I think this is a bug in javac compiler

Comment: @Пуя I encountered a similar issue a few times while troubleshooting a javac crash.  Here's the question I posted... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23701686/workaround-for-javac-crash-linux-rhel-5-maven-long-classpath-sigsegv-abstractstr.  I've only learned that the Java 7 javac crash seems fixed on Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 6.5 but frequently crashes on RHEL 5.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have stumbled upon a bug in compiler.

"Please file a bug at the Java Developer Connection (http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport)  after checking the Bug Parade for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report.  Thank you."

You may want to update your JDK to the latest version before that, though.

Comment: Downloading Oracle softwares in my country Iran is a real nightmare